# Objective-C : UIViewController get Data from ContainerView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicontainerview

This is my first time working with container views.

In my app's LoginViewController, I am using a container view which embeds a UITableViewController with two static cells which contain UITextFields for email and password.

When a user presses 'Login' button on LoginViewController, how can this class get the information from the UITableViewController embedded inside the container view?

Comment: It can get a reference to the contained view controller and read property values if you expose them, but why would you use a container for the form but not the login button. That seems completely unnecessary

Comment: @Paulw11, ok cool ... if I include the button in the container view, how then would I send the data to the uiviewcontroller for performing segues, etc

Comment: You would need to use a protocol to invoke a delegate method on the containing view controller, but I still don't see why you would complicate things by using a container view.  You can use a `UIView` to contain your controls if you want to without needing a whole view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the login form view controller in the `prepareForSegue(segue:sender:)` since container views trigger an embedded segue to the child View Controller.  Then have the login form View Controller expose the email and passwords.  The code below is in Swift, but there isn't anything magically Swifty about it.  It's just easier to demonstrate what I mean.

```
class LogInViewController : UIViewController {
   var logInForm : LogInFormViewController?
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if let child = segue.destinationViewController as? LogInFormViewController {
           logInForm = child
       }
   }
   @IBOutlet func logIn(sender: AnyObject?) {
       sendLogIn(logInForm?.email, logInForm?.password)
   }
}
class LogInFormTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    var email:String { get { return _emailField.text } }
    var password:String { get { return _passwordField.text } }
}
```

This can be extended to handle the enable/disable of the login button based on the form values if you need to.

To flip it and call back out the parent, like the comments discussion is talking about, use a protocol on the parent and attach it to the form during the perform segue action, just like above.

```
protocol LogInDelegate {
   func logIn(email:String, _ password:String)
}
class LogInViewController :UIViewController, LogInDelegate {
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if let child = segue.destinationViewController as? LogInFormViewController {
           child.logInDelegate = self
       }
   }
   func logIn(email: String, _ password:String) {
   }
}
class LogInFormTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var logInDelegate: LogInDelegate?
   @IBOutlet func logIn(sender: AnyObject?) {
       logInDelegate?.logIn(_emailField.text, _passwordField.text)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a delegate(Protocol) to call back
2. You can use NSNotification
3. You can write a lightweight call back block
4. I believe for the containerView and its childView, there is a property called parentViewController which you can refer to.